# Can you make a Wicket autocomplete field pop down using a button?

Tags: autocomplete, wicket-1.5

Is it possible to display the list of choices of a AutoCompleteTextField from a button.
(Javascript or something in the AutoCompleteTextField code?)

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Long answer needs more details like, what have you tried, what din't work out and why, where did you look for answers, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you need a button then it's not really an **auto**-complete anymore, is it?